# share link and base64 of image in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi am trying to share image and link using **react-native-share** am able to share it separately like `

```
const shareOptions = {
title: "Share Route via",
message: message,
url: "http://something.com/route"
//url :  "data:image/png;base64,base64string"
};

Share.open(shareOptions);
```

`

both image and url works when only adding one. When putting them together like this

```
const shareOptions = {
  title: "Share Route via",
  message: message,
  urls: [
    "http://something.com/route",
    "data:image/png;base64,base64string"
  ] 
};
Share.open(shareOptions);
```

it doesn't work

**EDIT 1**

There is no error but when I share the image only I could see the image in WhatsApp. But when I share both link and image(which is the base64string) it gets shared as that long base64string itself not as image

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please try to add TRY CATCH statement to the code and share the errors result with us.

Comment: could you check my question again I have updated it

Comment: Try sharing 2 images instead. It's likely that sharing text and image at the same time is not possible

Comment: I tried it it went as two image with whole text with each. i.e, two different items